# how to fill 0.00 values in float column like ffill or bfill?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a float column in which exsits some empty values written as 0.00.

How to fill these 0 values like using fillna(method='ffill')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `0` to missing values first:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].replace(0, np.nan).fillna(method='ffill').fillna(0)
```

Or:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].mask(df['col'] == 0).fillna(method='ffill').fillna(0)
```